# How would I go about performing a method through another method to the original $(this)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods

For example :

```
function masterMethod(this, action){
 // (action); <-- But action requires $(this) to be defined.
}

$(".item").click(function(){
  function minorMethod(){
   alert($(this));
  }
  masterMethod($(this), minorMethod)
});
```

How would I execute the action and pass $(this) in the masterMethod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`call` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
function masterMethod(element, action){
     action.call(element);
}

$(".item").click(function(){
    function minorMethod(){
        alert($(this));
    }
    masterMethod(this, minorMethod)
    // or directly here?
    // minorMethod.call(this)
});
```

Note the two changes I made: Instead of passing `$(this)` to `masterMethod`, I passed `this` (the DOM element), since inside `minorMethod`, you are passing `this` again to jQuery. If you were passing `$(this)` you would end up passing a jQuery object to jQuery again, i.e. `$($(this))`, which is unnecessary.

I'm not sure if it actually would throw an error, but in any case, you should not name your argument `this`.

Comment: Wow this is the most dead-on best way I could have possibly done this. Thank you so incredibly much. Thank you thank you thank you.